# Insert object, struct or array into a MySQL table in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, mono

Is there any way to simplify data insertion into a MySQL table making use of objects, structs or maybe arrays instead of writing long SQL queries with dozen of fields listed?

Say, I have a simple object of class (or struct) like this:

```
public class UserRecord
{
    public int id;
    public string first_name;
    public string last_name;
    public int age;

    // constructor, destructor, etc.
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to make use of standard C# libraries to implement such functionality like:

```
...
UserRecord user1 = new UserRecord("Hunter", "Thompson", 67);
database.Insert(user1);
...
```

Instead of something like:

```
...
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (... ...);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", user1.first_name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", user1.last_name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", user1.age);
...
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the ORM tools available?

Comment: @Marc, No. I'd like a kind of „non-automatic“ solution. I wonder if it is possible by deriving from some of a database related classes.

Comment: @ezpresso Check my answer. No way. There's no magic class which will convert a relational database access into an object-oriented one. Well, there's no such class: there's OR/M concept. This is the way to go, don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for OR/M. Since you're looking for a Mono-enabled solution, check **NHibernate**, one of best OR/M in the open source arena for the Microsoft .NET Framework:

- http://nhforge.org

If you want to learn more about what's an OR/M:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping

Answer (score 2):

I finally come up with the [PetaPoco library](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/). The "micro-ORM" library  which turned out to be very lightweight and easy to use. I find NHibernate to be very bloated for small applications like mine.

Below is the example of code I used to manage the UserRecords:

```
[PetaPoco.TableName("le_users")]
[PetaPoco.PrimaryKey("id")]
public class UserRecord
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}

...

// Create a PetaPoco database object
PetaPoco.Database db = new PetaPoco.Database(dbconnection);

// Insert a record
UserRecord rec = new UserRecord();
rec.first_name = "Hunter";
rec.last_name = "Thompson";
db.Insert(rec);
```

Thanks to everyone who pointed me out in the direction to ORM!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't go the OR/M way, you can use reflection for T but if the T contains properties non-related with your table record you must also use a custom attribute.

Comment: This way you'd be reinventing the wheel, creating a new weak OR/M.

Comment: You'are right. But ORM is just an option, not an obligation. As for the wheel reinvention in general, I'm sure that you have seen a lot of square wheels.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely, and this is painful, you know ;) That's why I prefer to argue no one should create its own OR/M, since existing ones are mature enough and they've proven quality, feature set and support.